# How to to produce both release and pre-release packages from one nuspec in VSTS?

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuspec, azure-artifacts

Currently my build produces both packages having a newer version every time:

```
Release: Automatic package versioning = Use the build number
Pre-release: Additional build properties = Version=$(user.BuildFullVersion)-beta
```

And the only one nuspec has a placeholder to version:

```
<version>$version$</version>
```

I want to increment version manually, that it - repetitive build would produce same version until I increment it manually.

How can I achieve that still having single nuspec?

Can I adjust package version in the pack tasks like this:

```
Release: $(PackageVersion) = $(PackageVersion)
Pre-release: $(PackageVersion) = $(PackageVersion)-beta
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To produce two packages by a nuspec, you can **use two NuGet tasks** (NuGet custom instead NuGet pack):

#### NuGet task:

Command: custom

Command and arguments:

```
pack $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Package.nuspec -Version $(Build.BuildNumber) -OutputDirectory $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

#### NuGet task:

Command: custom

Command and arguments:

```
pack $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Package.nuspec -Version $(Build.BuildNumber) -Suffix beta -OutputDirectory $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

---

If you set the `$(Build.BuildNumber)` as the format like `MyProject-Daily_1.0.94.0` while you want to add the version for nuget package as `1.0.94.0`, you can define a variable in your build definition and set the value by cutting the substring of `$(Build.BuildNumber)`. detail steps as below:

In **Variables Tab**, add a variable (such as `version`) with any value (such as `temp`).

[image]

Add a **PowerShell Task** before NuGet tasks with the settings,

Type: Inline Script

Inline Script:

```
$s1=$(Build.BuildNumber).split('_')[1].split(' ')
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version]$s1"
```

Then in the NuGet Custom tasks use `$(version)` to replace `$(Build.BuildNumber)` for `-version` option. Such as `nuget pack -version $(version)`.

Comment: Hi Marina, thanks for your response, it definitely helps! Few questions, please. When I used the built-in pack command it passes the version properly, e.g. `-version 1.0.94.0`. But when I use `-Version $(Build.BuildNumber)` it becomes `-Version MyProject-Daily_1.0.94.0` what of course doesn't work. What is the variable the built-in command uses?

Comment: Also do I understand correctly that custom command doesn't support wildcard path, it needs one nuspec at a time?

Comment: I added the method to use the version like `1.0.94.0` for nuget packages, you can find it in the end of my answer. And yes, the custom commands doesn't support wildcards.

Comment: Oh, bummer. That's a showstopper for us then. We have several projects within single repo ("shared") and single build/release definitions we'd like to pack. Creating separate step for each would be too much hassle.