# Nuget Continuous Integration Process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm getting started with a Continuous Integration Nuget feed for my team using a network share. After each build to the dev environment, a package will be created on the network share using the versioning scheme Major.Minor.Patch.BuildNumber. Example: "MyPackage.1.1.3.16338.nupkg".

I was planning to have apps reference these packages on the local feed, and whichever package version is released to Production is published to Artifactory and considered the latest "stable" package/build.

The problem is, I know the versioning scheme doesn't conform to Semantic Versioning and I don't like the ugly build number at the end of the version.

Is there a better way to do this, so I end up with a simple 1.1.3 version to publish to Artifactory at the end of a release cycle?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to do this, so I end up with a simple 1.1.3 version to publish to Artifactory at the end of a release cycle?

I think the best way to do that is using versioning scheme `Major.Minor.Patch` instead of `Major.Minor.Patch.BuildNumber`, otherwise, you have to manually change the package version from `1.1.3.16338` to `1.1.3`. Because there is no such option or task that we could change the package version after creation.

As an alternative, you could use nuget task **NuGet custom** to create the nuget package:

[image]

NuGet task:
Command: custom

Command and arguments:

```
pack $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Package.nuspec -Version $(version) -OutputDirectory $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

In this case, you can specify the nuget package version in the command line.

See [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601861/how-to-to-produce-both-release-and-pre-release-packages-from-one-nuspec-in-vsts/45607639) for some more details.